# Accessing custom property of mesh data through Attribute Node in Shader Editor

Tags: materials, properties, shader-nodes

Accessing custom properties of **object data** through the Attribute Node works just fine but custom property in **mesh data** does not. Even though the documentation says:

> The name or path is looked up first in the object data-block, followed
> by the mesh data-block if not found.

Since my object contains a mesh and the custom property I look for is defined only in the mesh level, i was expecting to be able to access it through the Attribute Node but Blender does not seem to find it.
Am I misunderstanding the doc ?

Documentation also talks about "path". Maybe I can access the mesh custom property through a specific path, I tried to copy-paste data-path / full data-path but sadly it does not work. Any idea ?

Comment: I assume it's because object properties are evaluated only once with the mesh they are using, but on the other hand it looks for values on each individual vertex of the mesh in case you choose Geometry in the Attribute node. Long story short, you can access it but you have to first convert it either into an attribute stored on the mesh or on a vertex color layer, but you are limited to 8 maximum. Both can be done with python scripting